# Convertir kotlin a java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

me preguntaba si alguien me podría ayudar a traducir una función que tengo en kotlin a java, no soy muy bueno , pero el único ejemplo que he visto que me pueda servir esta en kotlin y todo mi proyecto lo tengo en java. gracias.

```
class ExpGoogle {
    var SPREAD_SHEET_ID = "2PACX-1vTmVEaepBN58p4XsEfhALtESTLFMlaipQu4fehtNm2EGK0OD25RVhBxuXv24TnuEJjwi1qZA7bhA-"
    var TABLE_USERS = "RevisionRamos"
   
    fun addDatos () {
        /* Montamos un JSON como este:
         * {"spreadsheet_id":"1jBtXZdoxIYJlEAnJ8YbQ3NbUmPrBFqgtSbmMHMIQMck", "sheet": "users", "rows":[["4", "Juan", "juan@gmail.com"], ["5", "Maria", "maria@gmail.com"]]}
         */
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("spreadsheet_id", SPREAD_SHEET_ID)
        jsonObject.put("RevisionRamos", TABLE_USERS)

        val rowsArray = JSONArray()
        val row1 = JSONArray()

        row1.put("02/17/2021")
        row1.put("BLANCA")
        row1.put("86")
        row1.put("4")
        row1.put("0.25")

        jsonObject.put("rows", rowsArray)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(addRowURL, jsonObject,
                Response.Listener { response ->

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Datos enregistrados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    error.printStackTrace()
                }
        )
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso lo puede hacer android studio. Simplemente necesitas crear un archivo .kt , pegar el código y luego seguir este recorrido: Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode > Decompile. Aunque perfectamente puedes tener un archivo en kotlin  y el resto de tu proyecto en Java. Todo lo que debes hacer es aceptar el mensaje que android studio muestre cuando crees un archivo .kt

Comment: Simplemente pega el código.